# Algorithm for the maximal combinations in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

I have an array which is for example of a length of 4 elemnts
no I want to know how to calculate the possible combinations when using 3 digets out of it.

eg:

```
3 6 2
3 6 8
6 2 8
8 3 2
```

my array is : 3 6 2 8

there are 4 possibilitys, but how can I count them programaticly ?

Comment: Are you looking for [Choose(n,k)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)? (In your case `Choose(4,3) = 4!/3!*1! = 4`, as expected)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Love how he tagged his question with "algorithm."

Comment: Subgroup algorithm is the THING for you. [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup)

Comment: @OrelEraki Subgroup? where is the group? What is the binary operator? Did you mean *subset*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that what you are actually looking for is **[`Choose(n,k)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)**, which is the number of ways to chose `k` elements out of `n` candidates.

The formula for it is basically `Choose(n,k) = n! / (k! * (n-k)!)`

The rational behind it is:

Number of ways to sort `n` items (n! possibilities) and then choose first `k`. After you have chosen you don't care for the order of the first `k` items (`k!` possibilities) and the last `n-k` items (`(n-k)!` possibilities).

In your example, `Choose(4,3) = 4!/(3!*1!) = 4`, as expected.

Comment: You might want to talk about what happens if there are duplicate elements in the original list; it changes the math a bit.

Comment: is there also a way to count the occurence of each element ?

Comment: @templatetypedef I believe it changes the math a lot. I think it should be done with inclusion-exclusion if elements are not unique. I'll try to do the math later on today.

Comment: @AlexanderFuchs No, it does not. If elements are not unique please explicitly say it in the question (and un-accept my answer, since it does not fit the question, I will delete it once you unaccept it)

Comment: yes they are unique. I want to count the occurence of them inside the combination.E.g how oftem occures 8

Comment: to count the occurrences of a number in all permutations (equal for all numbers), you calculate (n-1) choose (k-1) where n is the number of elements and k is the number of items per permutation. In your case, n = 4 and k = 3, so the occurrence of every number in all permutations is 3 choose 2 (or as amit formulated it, choose(3, 2)).